# Cómo puedo correctamente exportar un programa Python a ejecutable de un solo archivo usando pyinstaller sin que el antivirus arroje un falso positivo?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, ingenieria-del-software, código-abierto

He creado un programa toma algunas imágenes de la ruta de un usuario y crea otras nuevas usando ciertas librerías.

Después de esto para poder exportar dicho programa como un ejecutable, que no obligase al usuario a descargar Python y las librerías correspondientes para poder ejecutarlo, instalé `pyinstaller` y abrí el `Símbolo del sistema`, luego fui a la `ruta` correspondiente en la que estaba mi programa `SAND-wich.py` a exportar, y escribí el siguiente código en la consola:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=./SAND-wich_icon.ico SAND-wich.py
```

A continuación, les muestro parte del `output` que generó dicha sentencia de arriba em mi consola:

```
59 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7

59 INFO: Python: 3.9.6

67 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0

68 INFO: wrote C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Pictures\Cryptobote\SAND-wich.spec
 
70 INFO: UPX is not available.
 
71 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths

.
.
.

37164 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0

37166 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE

43588 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

pyinstaller --onefile --icon=./SAND-wich_icon.ico SAND-wich.py
```

Luego al mirar los resultados en la ruta específicada del usuario se encuentra lo siguiente:

[image: Carpetas y archivos creados con pyinstaller]

Lo que valida que efectivamente mi programa fue convertido a ejecutable sin problema alguno, *aparentemente*.

Luego entro a la carpeta `dist`, la cual es la carpeta que me interesa pues tiene el archivo ejecutable final, el cual es el siguiente:

[image: archivo SAND-wich.exe]

Y aquí es donde aparece el problema de "**falso positivo**", inmediatamente al abrirlo:

[image: Problema de falso positivo con AVG]

De hecho, no está ejecutando correctamente, pues al pasarle la ruta en donde ejecutara sus funciones no detecta ninguna carpeta con sus archivos de imagen:

[image: Problema después de exportar como ejecutable]

Lo que no debería ser así, puesto que `SAND-wich.py` sí hace lo que debe hacer.

[image: Ejecución correcta del programa SAND-wich.py]

Presiento que tiene que ver con el problema de **"falso positivo"** de algún modo.

También intenté convertir mi programa a ejecutable sin usar `--onefile` pero sólo crea carpetas vacías, por culpa del antivirus también, no sé qué hacer para solucionar esto, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Lo del falso positivo es inevitable. Aquí más información aqui: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2988#issuecomment-343674665 Sobre la detección de las carpetas, estás ejecutando tu exe como administrador?

Comment: Sí, lo estoy ejecutando como administrador y estoy obteniendo la incorrecta salida @DanteS.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/8bbba1ab103267ab894b3c1e18427336b0176796409672dc2404fd20b48c20e9?nocache=1. Instala la versión de pyinstall en desarrollo..
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop y por lo menos a windows defender y al AVG resulta negativo.